# Map to return `(Wrap<A>|Wrap<B>)[]` instead of `Wrap<A|B>[]`

Tags: typescript

I am trying to solve code:

```js
type Wrap<T> = {
    value: T
}
function wrapIt<T>(t: T): Wrap<T> {
    return { value: t}
}
const arr: Array<string|number> = ["a", 1]
const arr2: Array<Wrap<string|number>> = arr.map(wrapIt)
const arr3: Array<Wrap<string>|Wrap<number>> = arr.map(wrapIt) // <--- Doesn't compile
```

The compiler says:

```
Type 'Wrap<string | number>[]' is not assignable to type '(Wrap<string> | Wrap<number>)[]'.
  Type 'Wrap<string | number>' is not assignable to type 'Wrap<string> | Wrap<number>'.
    Type 'Wrap<string | number>' is not assignable to type 'Wrap<string>'.
      Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

`arr3` is what I need for being compatible with some other code I dont own. Also, conceptually, it seems more correct.

Is there some typescript black magic to make it behave the way I want?
For now I will type cast it using `as`.

EDIT: `Array<string|number>` was just used as an example, I am using this pattern quite often so I would like the solution to work for `Array<T>` where `T` is arbitrary and can be a union like `string|number` but not just.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the definition of the function to distribute over `T` when returning the type. So this means that when mapping a union (such as `number | string`) you will get a union of instantiations of `Wrapped` for each union constituent (so `Wrapped<number> | Wrapped<string>`) not an instantiation of `Wrapped` for the union (so not `Wrapped<string | number>`)

```
type DistraibutiveWrapped<T> = T extends T ? Wrap<T> : never
function wrapIt<T>(t: T): DistraibutiveWrapped<T> {
    return { value: t} as DistraibutiveWrapped<T>
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gTgQzAHgCoD4oF4oG8CwAUFCVAG4IA2ArhAFxSpEC+RRokUAIgJYDOwRDwBG1YDzIR4SSABM0mHKigQAHsAgA7WX0ZQA-LEQoMUBtJPoiAM2qaAxuID2mqAHdjASWAKAFMAZUAEoGXgEhUXFJCzkFPCJSKDgIYGo4V1xyKloGYGYoBF0wwQQRMQkpY1iMFiJ7FwECuDgGAEFmhBBkcJ5NAHMAH01qAFthCDhFKABtACIEWYAaKABGAF06huAmuAAmNo6ui27BXsHhsYn0KYRmgDoRpF8PJG8gzc1G27gAZgPEI7GE5wM7oAbHC7jSY3e6PMDPLzAIJQIA)

Answer (score 1):

Using explicit type checking?

```js
type Wrap<T> = {
  value: T
}
function wrapIt<T>(t: T): Wrap<T> {
  return { value: t }
}
const arr: Array<string | number> = ["a", 1]
const arr2: Array<Wrap<string | number>> = arr.map(wrapIt)
const arr3: Array<Wrap<string> | Wrap<number>> = arr.map(x => {

  switch (typeof x) {
    case 'string':
      return wrapIt<string>(x);
    case 'number':
      return wrapIt<number>(x);
    default:
      return wrapIt(x);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that work so I upvote. I am not a big fan of having extra runtime code just to make the compiler happy though.

Answer (score 0):

You can create extra function and [overload it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```js
type Wrap<T> = {
    value: T
}
function wrapIt<T>(t: T): Wrap<T> {
    return { value: t }
}
const arr: Array<string | number> = ["a", 1]

function map<Item,>(arr: Item[]): Array<Wrap<string> | Wrap<number>>
function map<Item,>(arr: Item[]) {
    return arr.map(wrapIt)
}

// (Wrap<string> | Wrap<number>)[] which is equivalent to Array<Wrap<string> | Wrap<number>>, just different syntax
const result = map(['hello', 42])
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NlxaxN)